# If there a way I can inner join a MS Sql table to a MySql Table in one query using MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have 2 servers one servers runs Microsoft SQL Server and the other one is using MySql.

I need to be able to inner join a table from MS SQL name it "A" to a table "B" located on a different server that uses MySql

So I want to be able to do something like this

`SELECT A.*, B.* FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id=B.id LIMIT 100`

How can I do this? note that both servers are on the same network.

Comment: You might be able to accomplish that with ODBC, but neither m(y|s)sql can talk to each other directly.

Comment: You could use a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) from SQL Server, but they often have issues with performance and data type compatibility so it may not be an ideal solution. And it would mean running the query on SQL Server, not MySQL, which is the opposite of what you wanted (but perhaps you have some flexibility).

Comment: Thanks guys for your feedback. @Pindlife, yes I don't think this will work because I am using MySql for everything else. Marc B, How can I use the ODBC to do that? can you please help me with an example?

Comment: Where up to i Know Best way for such cases to use some Scripting Language(`PHP\ASP`) etc. between two different RDMBS, to produce Pseudo JOINs

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan I am using PHP to generate my reports. But how can I pull the data from both sources?

Comment: Dear Use Two Connections with both Databases. it will fairly simple;

Comment: @MuhammadHaseebKhan  How can I do that? It may be fairly simple to a person with experience like yourself but not for me :)  I will aprechiate it more it you give me an example? in order to get the results that i need for this reports I will need to do an inner joing between tables. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st link on google states...

you need to install this:

http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

and follow this guide:

http://technikhil.wordpress.com/2007/05/13/getting-microsoft-sql-server-and-mysql-to-talk/

to link up the servers and then use openquery to execute MS SQL queries.

Comment: you might have to face lot of compatiability issues

Comment: why would OpenQuery have issues?  Reading above it sounds like he's using php, which I would probably use over this approach, though I'd still consider architecture.

Comment: I am USING PHP yes. But how can I use PHP to connunicate to servers? I am using PDO to connect to my mysql server

Comment: @RandomUs1r I have installed MySql ODBC Driver  but in the second think it show a code to connect to mysql server. I am trying to connect to SQL server. how can I do that?  how to I change this code to connect to SQL server from MySql  
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver server = N'MYSQL', srvproduct=N'MySQL', provider=N'MSDASQL', provstr=N'DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=DB_Name; USER=UserName; PASSWORD=Password; OPTION=3'   ?

Comment: @Mike here's sample code on php + ms sql: http://webcheatsheet.com/PHP/connect_mssql_database.php .  From there you load up the data into php and dump it into mysql

Comment: @Mike in regards to your 2nd post, that user needs to exist on the ms sql server, so whatever user you're adding the linked server to needs to exist on ms sql server see https://support.gearhost.com/KB/a453/adding-users-to-mssql-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx .

Comment: No problem, out of curiosity, which approach did you wind up taking? PHP or linked server?