# Compare two database tables of differing types and compare their data?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have two database tables from 2 different databases, one in MYSQL and one in MSSQL. Both have similar data, and one is somewhat based on data from another (Only some columns in common). They're in two different databases because one is a remote system used for Crystal Reports (MSSQL) and another is used to run our Workflow Management System (MYSQL).

MSSQL Database Table - Job_Operation

```
Job_OperationKey | Job_Operation | Vendor | Work_Center | Job | Etc...
```

MYSQL Database Table - View_Job_Info

```
Id | job_num | posted_date | columns etc.. | latest_workorder_date |
```

The best comparison that can be done that I can see is between Job and job_num. This way, if Job #### matches job_num #### then tabulate columns from both tables into 1 table. I'm not sure how plausible this is because I've ran into memory issues querying everything from Job_Operation when using Adminer.

The thing is, I don't need every single job, I just need jobs that match up to this particular query:

```
Select * 
    FROM view_job_info 
    WHERE (DATEDIFF(NOW(), latest_workorder_date) < 90 OR (DATEDIFF(NOW(), posted_date) < 30)) 
        AND job_num > 2000`
```

This way I can get the current active jobs.

How can this be made possible?

Comment: Why not connect to the MYSQL database with Crystal Reports, and join the two tables together in there?

Comment: @mikeoscarecho what do you mean by "tablulate columns from both tables into 1 table" and is that your only requirement?

Comment: @OliverLockett I'm on a Linux machine but I didn't even know that was possible. If I do that some how I would still have to merge the data somehow, check both Job and job_num columns and if both match then store them in a table? Can I query Crystal using PHP to output data to a page?

Comment: @Punter015 If column Job from Table1 matches column job_num from Table2, insert all data from both tables into another table. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry - I have very little experience with PHP. However a google search tells me it is possible....
I don't know really what you're trying to achieve. Are you looking for a long standing report to check data integrity, or is this a one off job? If it's long term then maybe this wouldn't be your best option. I don't think you'd need to create a table for this - Crystal should just be able to generate a query that joins the data together ready for output.

Comment: @OliverLockett Yea I'm not sure what you suggested is possible. My end goal is to graph the jobs on a web page to display total hours spent on an active job. If a bar on the bargraph is clicked for a particular job it'll drill down to specific departments.

Comment: Ah - does this need to be live or historical?

Comment: And are both databases on the same server?

Comment: @OliverLockett Hmm, somewhat historical, as in the data has to be a week old at all times because certain data (like hours spent per machine or department) is usually submitted to the MSSQL database Friday afternoons.

Comment: @OliverLockett They are not. The database that holds view_job_info is on a linux server and the database that holds Job_Operation is on a Windows Server however I do have access to it on my Linux machine and can see all tables + data.

Comment: there are a couple of solutions here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220490/if-there-a-way-i-can-inner-join-a-ms-sql-table-to-a-mysql-table-in-one-query-usi

but I would probably set up a job to copy the SQL server job table to the mysql database once a week, and then you can query everything from there.

Speak to your dba - he'll be able to set that up easy

Comment: @MikeOscarEcho may be you can query data in MySQL from MSSQL (Like linked_server in MSSQL) and create a view in MySQL joining both the tables to display your wanted result. That would be a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a linked server from MSSQL to MySQL.
2. Access the MySQL table in MSSQL -- Ex. 
   `select * from openquery(test,'select * from MySQL_Table)` , Test is the linked server     name and MySQL_Table is the table in MySQL
3. Put the output of the above query into a temporary table.
4. Inner join the temporary table with the MSSQL Table on job_num and job.
5. output of the result of the above can be used in any way you want.

more over contact your database administor to perform the above activities.
refer this http://www.packtpub.com/article/mysql-linked-server-on-sql-server-2008 to create the linked server in MSSQL.

Comment: Thanks for the step by step, I'll get working on it and report back if I need more clarification on something.