# Cross Database Joins Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have 2 connection in my Doctrine with ZF2, but i need make join in twoo databases. The big question is: is it possible to perform a join on two tables which are in different databases and connections?

```
'connection' => array(
            // Default DB connection
           'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'user' => 'root',
                    'port' => '3306',
                    'password' => '',
                    'dbname' => 'MYSQL_TEST',
                    'driverOptions' => array(
                        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
                    )
                ),
            ),

            // Alternative DB connection
            'orm_alternative' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlsrv\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'user' => 'sa',
                    'port' => '',
                    'password' => 'test',
                    'dbname' => 'MSSQL_TEST',
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Entity MYSQL Example:

```
   /**
     * mysql_test
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="mysql_table")
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MYSQL\Entity\TestRepository")
     */
    class Test
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
        private $id;

         /**
         * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MSSQL\Entity\Test")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_mssql", referencedColumnName="id_mssql")
         */
        private $mssql;
```

I would like to make a join between these two connections :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer you are probably looking for is, unfortunately, **no**.

There are ways for two separate connections (mysql and mssql in your case) to share data and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220490/if-there-a-way-i-can-inner-join-a-ms-sql-table-to-a-mysql-table-in-one-query-usi) might lead you down the right track if you are feeling extra adventurous.

But I would recommend just selecting your data from each connection separately and then manipulating it in `php` by matching common keys from each result to essentially emulate a join.